# View not expanding because of status bar

Tags: ios, autolayout

I put two views inside my storyboard and created equal heights and widths constraints, plus set leading, trailing, top constraint to zero. I made sure there were no "Constraint to margins" constraints. Though, the view on the right doesn't expand to the full, whereas the one on the left does.

[image]

[Here's a link to the project.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcc0h8y1n4lwi5o/ViewNotExanding.zip?dl=0) Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: can you share your project? hard to tell whats going wrong without...

Comment: I put a link in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that your blue view has a top constraint to the toplayoutguide instead of its superview. remove the constraint and readd it but make sure that you use the View instead of the Top Layout Guide!

[image: top constraint]